# How to differentiate UI binding Model objects and Model objects which are passed to middle tier

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

==> a) UI Model objects: i.e  class which I have properties change notification (INotifyPropertyChanged), SelectedItemXXX  binded to Some ComboBox SelectedItem

==> b) Model Objects : Just plain objecti.e POCO (Plain Old CLR Object)

Question 1) In general whats the better to have such models.I mean do we need just maintain only model (a) ?

Question 2) If we maintain two models.Whats  better way to have. Can we have some association or some method to generate model object (b).

Question 3) Whats the name convention in general followed if we have two models.
            I named it like PersonUI, Person I mean is any better way for naming?

Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

Answer to question 1: **No**.  You often require simple model objects to perform real world business logic (aka domain logic) outside the realm of your UI models.  Following the [Single Responsibility Principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), you should not convolute your UI model objects with business model objects.

Answer to question 2:  **Yes** - A very common used pattern is [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) :

- M - represents the Model (business or domain logic layer)
- V - represents the View (in WPF and Silverlight it is XAML and code behind)
- VM  represents the ViewModel (or in your words the UI Model objects)

MVVM is recommended best practice for both WPF and SilverLight.  It separates the UI from the Model and allows for easier testing and reuse.

Answer to question 3: A common naming convention for your UI model objects (a) is to use **`XXXXViewModel`**.  For example if you have a WPF control named `Giraffe.xaml` and corresponding code behind file of `Giraffe.xaml.cs`, then the name your view model file would be `GiraffeViewModel.cs` and class would look something like:

`public class GiraffeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{..`

Keep the names of model objects to the logic that is contained inside.  For example: `GiraffeVision.cs`

Comment: Here is the problem with naming convention .Lets we have  Employee Register View  and  corresponding view Model i.e EmployeeRegisterViewModel. Now EmployeeRegisterView  needs some  kind object which need to be bounded to specific UI control lets say EmployeePersonal information where need to catch  SelectedItem  . if I name that object as EmployeePersonalInfoViewModel then its going to be long list of ViewModels  which confuses when we want to search the MainViewModel(EmployeeRegisterViewModel) to work with some kind of getting data issue.. like for GetData is not working.

Comment: In that case, your EmployeePersonalInformation objects would be an ObservableCollection property in the EmployeeRegisterViewModel.  ObservableCollections are lists of Model object used in Grids, or Templates so you can display many of them on your view.  See http://wpfgrid.blogspot.de/2014/02/simple-observablecollection-wpf-mvvm.html - notice the Trades model class midway down.  This domain model is put into an ObservableCollection  to be displayed dynamically in the TradesView.

Comment: In actual case its not a collection object .I just  gave  sample scenario.We need to maintain bind able objects  which are not collection Items .They are like one to one .But I need to get information from UI control. This UI control should be binded to some object (i.e INotifiable, SelectedXXX..) .Its actually ViewModel .But now if i name it as XXX_ViewModel...  its confusing alot... to search the files.. to find MainViewModel( where actual logic goes for calling middle tier, and other comamnds stuff).

Comment: well if your controls are reusable, then they can be broken down and coded in separate XXX.xaml files and you can also have control level XXXXViewModel.cs files to follow the naming convention.  Its typically  better for reuse and testing to have smaller reusable UI elements.  Please post specific question to your problem and we can provide more specific solution and answers for you.